# The constructor and render function is called twice

Tags: reactjs

I have a very simple component, in that I log the information to check the Component Lifecycle and see that the constructor and render function is called twice every time when I reload the browser. Could anyone please help me to review why?

Here is my code, and the result in the picture.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'Viet'
    };

    console.log('App constructor');
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('App componentWillMount');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('App componentDidMount');
  }

  changeState = () => {
    this.setState({ name: 'Viet is changed' })
  }


  render() {

    console.log('App render');

    return (
      <div className='App'>
        {this.state.name}
        {<button onClick={this.changeState.bind(this)} >Click to change state</button>}

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your render method you are not passing the function right due to which component is re-rendered again. You need to bind the function in constructor change the `onClick` of button as:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'Viet'
    };

    console.log('App constructor');
    this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this);
  }

<button onClick={this.changeState}>Click to change state</button>
```

Comment: Damn, too fast :p

Comment: Wait, I still don't get it why it rendered twice because of this, and I think the way OP wrote is also legit.

Comment: Because he is calling the function in onClick which is being executed right away

Comment: I think my code is legit, the function changeState is not the rootcause, I tried to remove the button and the function changeState, but still render twice.

Comment: The code is legit, in a sense, it compiles. But as it is written, the function `changeState` will be executed when 'parsed' by Javascript, which is not what you want. Instead, you want the function to be executed only on the `onClick`. To achieve that, you must write the statement as in @MuhammadZeeshan's answer.

Comment: @ArthurAttout, my concern is why the constructor and render is called twice even if I remove the button away. `import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'Viet'
    };

    console.log('App constructor');
  }

 
  render() {

    console.log('App render');

    return (
      <div className='App'>      

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;`

Answer (score 0):

The double rendering is due to `React.StrictMode`. If you check your `src/index.js` the App Component is wrapped with `React.StrictMode` tags.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**As mentioned in the release notes**:
*"React.StrictMode is a wrapper to help prepare apps for async rendering"*

P.S: There is nothing to worry about re-rendering.